# Refresh Simulink S-function block

Tags: simulink

I have an `S-function` block in `Simulink`, which does not update when I change the number of input ports in its .C source file. I recompile the code and then I would like to modify the block's mask and add one more port label but I get the error saying that the number of input ports has been exceeded. How do I force `Simulink` to reload that `S-function` block? I already tried `Diagram->Refresh blocks` with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the error... Simulink calls `mdlInitializeSizes` to figure out the block's number of inputs and outputs. However, I also have some parameters that I pass to the `S-function` and those were not initialized and hence `mdlInitializeSizes` could not run. Fixed.